# FT Server Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ftp, ssl

I am creating FTP server (vsftpd) on GCP. After resolving several errors throughout the process. finally, I am able to connect with the FTP server via Filezilla and Winscp too. I am getting a warning Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS. What's the reason behind it.

```
#/etc/vsftpd.conf
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
write_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
#PassiveMode_settings
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Ports Opened
tcp:20,21,990,40000-50000,443,22

Answer (score 1):

> ssl_enable=NO

It clearly says NO SSL.

Comment: Are SSL and TLS synonyms? I don't think so. For a newbie it's not even obvious they are related, so pointing out "it *clearly* says" is hardly helpful. For someone who doesn't already know, this answer leads to more questions. Will changing the option to `YES` enable TLS? Or will enabling SSL make the warning stop, despite the fact the warning mentions TLS? Can you make the answer more informative?

Comment: Well, I did enable ssl_enable=NO before posting the question here. but after that my FTP account stoped working. I have to guess that there are some other options related to the SSL which I want to know..

Comment: @TalhaNasim: I recommend to look at the documentation or tutorials (like [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-vsftpd-ssl/)). Setting `enable_ssl=YES` should be obvious went wanting SSL. As for "stopped working" you better look at the error messages from vsftp for more information. But that's another question.